# vb.net : Show IP, Subnet, Gateway, DNS in RichTextBox and only from one in Labels?

Tags: vb.net, dns, ip

I hope you can help me.
I got 2 questions :

1. How can I show the DNS address in this code ?

   ```
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    RichTextBox1.Clear()
    For Each adapter In System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
        Dim adapters As NetworkInterface() = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
        Dim IpAddress As UnicastIPAddressInformation
        For Each IpAddress In adapter.GetIPProperties.UnicastAddresses
            ' Get IP and Subnet information 
            RichTextBox1.AppendText("IP Addresse : " & IpAddress.Address.ToString & vbCrLf)
            RichTextBox1.AppendText("Subnetmask : " & IpAddress.IPv4Mask.ToString & vbCrLf)
        Next
        For Each gatewayAddr As System.Net.NetworkInformation.GatewayIPAddressInformation In adapter.GetIPProperties.GatewayAddresses
            ' Get IP gateway information  
            RichTextBox1.AppendText("Gateway : " & gatewayAddr.Address.ToString & vbCrLf)
        Next
        ' ?????????????????????????????????? Get DNS information ???????????????????????????????????
    Next
   ```
2. In my RichTextBox are the in the information of all LAN-Adapters (4 pieces at this computer) with my code below. Thats ok.
   But is it possible to get the information of only one Adapter, which is called "LAN-Connection 3" and to show this informations (IP, Subnet, Gateway, DNS) in 4 Labels?
   Could you show me the code please, if it´s possible?

Comment: Please properly format your code. SO editor provides a button for this.

Comment: yes I know, but the button doesn´t do it in code format. I tried ctrl+k too.Now it works

Comment: I assume this is VB.Net

Comment: yes, you are right. it´s vb.net